# Spinner android change items according to time (months)

Tags: android

i have spinner that include months (From January to december). Now we are in april and i need to display first item april without destroy order. (When i enter to app it will display april, in next month may automatically). 
I also have date in my project if that will help.[It's how app look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8RVm.jpg)
Thank for help))

Comment: what do you mean by destroy order? List that you pass to spinner will always start from Jan and end with December I mean will the first item always be Jan and last item will be december?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple problem to solve, you can get the current date from the system and then, get the current month, in Kotlin language:

```kotlin
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
// will return a 0 (January) to 11 (December) number
val currentMonth = calendar[Calendar.MONTH]
// set your spinner to current item
mySpinner.setSelection(currentMonth)
```

Or in Java:

```java
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
mySpinner.setSelection(currentMonth);
```

You can set this in after setup the Spinner, for example.